# Xamarin Forms on iOS, while debugging elements turns to null

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms App, it works fine, but on click events it doesn't work, I tried to debug and noticed that my gui objects are all turned to null, I don't even know why, I tried to compare it with null and re-initialize then, but this if-statement just was ignored by mono! What the heck?

here is my class:
http://pastebin.com/jDufJ9sb

ActivityIndicator turn to null I don't know when, but when I check it on 224 line, and Debugger shows that it is null, but if-statement doesn't run properly

Comment: Please don't post links to offsite content.  Take the time to post the **relevant** portions of your code directly in your question.  Expecting a stranger to debug 500 lines of code for you is asking a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using async method for views initialization:

```
private async Task Load(Profile profile)
```

There're places where you call that function (eg. line 70):

- without await (so fire and forget)
- without using Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread. Remember: **All operations on UI must be done from UI thread.**